# Modeling nested child collections in Redis

Tags: redis, data-modeling

The goal is modeling multiple nested collections, the data model is like this:

- One Product has multiple Features.
- One Feature has one property (doesn't mind) and multiple Toggles.
- One Toggle has one property (doesn't mind) and multiple Parameters.
- Parameter is key-value type.

In the app the data model is gonna be queried by the Feature and Product names, so the Feature name is not unique and **the goal is getting the Feature full of children** (Toggle and Parameters).

I imagine something like this, but my background is ahead of key-value stores:

- **MyProduct:features** 1 2 3 4 5
- **feature:1** name value
- **feature:1** other_field value
- **feature:1:toggles** 1 2 3 4 5
- **toggle:1** name value
- **toggle:1** other_field value
- **toggle:1:parameters** 1 2 3 4 5
- **parameter:1** field value

Other approach:

- **MyProduct:feature1** other_field value
- **MyProduct:feature1:toggle1** other_field value
- **MyProduct:feature1:toggle1:parameter1** field value

So yeah, i'm totally lost
Thanks for all guys!!